# How to execute a shell command using python and write regex to see if the user is root or not..?

Tags: python, shell

For Ex:

1.open a terminal 
2. user:~$ 
3. Write a regex to verify if the command can be executed by root or not by verifying $ or # (for user/root)

```
def fun(cmd):
     # ----
     return data

stdin,stdout,stderr=fun()
```

I want to see if the function worked properly or not(if not print error status code...!)

Comment: Why use regex??

Comment: That's the most roundabout way I've ever seen for determining if a user is root.  Is there a specific reason you want to do it that way?

Comment: How about `os.geteuid()`?